# Can I use Aliyun VPS server for wechat mini-program?

Tags: vps, wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I am new to wechat development, as I can see from the documentation it requires setting up a server, getting a domain and ssl certificate. I am developing an app that sends a request to a server, fetches pdf file from database and downloads that file to user's phone. Since I am using pdf, I need to store binary data, so VPS hosting should be the best option here. But I am not sure if I can use it for WeChat, I noticed in most documentation and tutorials developers are using cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.whatever serve provider is.